# Crash of UWP's HID library

Tags: c#, uwp, hid

I am developing a UWP application to work with HID devices. The application is working correctly almost all the time. But it often crashes when I close or collapse/restore. I got exception Access violation reading location:

```
Exception thrown at 0x5FC8A31C (Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000001E.
```

And this exception always appears on CreateOutputReport method.

How can I check the possibility of the creation of the output report?
Or how can I handle this exception in UWP?

Thanks for any advice in advance.

UPD: Here is a code sample

```
HidDevice device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
if(device != null)
{
    var outReport = device.CreateOutputReport(); // Crashes here only on collapsing/closing
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)outReport.Data.Capacity];
    outReport.Data = buffer.AsBuffer();
    await device.SendOutputReportAsync(outReport);
}
```

UPD 2: Tested from scratch. Created UWP app with this code:

```
public async void StartSending()
{
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vid, pid));

    if (devices.Any())
    {
        var device = devices.FirstOrDefault();

        HidDevice hidDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        if (hidDevice != null)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                var outReport = hidDevice.CreateOutputReport();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)outReport.Data.Capacity];

                // fill data

                outReport.Data = buffer.AsBuffer();
                await hidDevice.SendOutputReportAsync(outReport);

                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great until I collapse the application. Application failed after restoring. But this appears only on the installed app. It works correctly from VS.

[Video](http://grabilla.com/08a0a-62f63388-14a0-4757-bd19-767f12afca4b.mp4)

Comment: Most likely, you have sent something into the API functions that has gone out of scope or have been deleted. You need to supply your code for someone to be able to help you

Comment: @Rolle, I've added a code sample. API functions are used correctly since they work perfectly 99% of the time. But they failed ONLY on collapsing/closing. I think Windows suspends the application and releases some resources from HID library. But I'm disappointed why I haven't any instruments to catch this error or to prevent it.

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue is in your code or other places. Please try to use another device to test to see if you will face this issue. And if possible, please provide a [mcve]. You could upload it and post link here.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, added the code snippet and video

Comment: Your code still might be not complete. Have you done some operations when app suspend and resume? You could check the exception message in [Application.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responses.
[XavierXie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782612) was right, I haven't any logic for suspending/resuming. It works now.

Here is code:

```
Application.Current.Suspending += OnSuspending;
Application.Current.Resuming += OnResuming;

private void OnResuming(object sender, object e)
{
    // Reinitialize all watchers for HID
    // Subscribe to all necessary events
}

private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    // Remove all watchers for HID
    // Unsubscribe from all events
    // Dispose all active HID devices
}
```